# Fragments RootViews AND/OR Databinding variable Leaking

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, leakcanary

I am using BottomNavigationView and switching between between Fragments in onNavigationItemSelected because i want custom enter and exit animations.

However my fragment root views AND/OR the databinding variables are leaking in the process.

See below LeakCanary Analysis. The `clFeedFragmentRoot` is the root view of `FragmentMainFeed` and

`feedBinding` is `FragmentMainFeedBinding`.

```
├─ com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzq
│    Leaking: NO (zzq↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
│    GC Root: System class
│    ↓ static zzq.zzbmc
├─ com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzq
│    Leaking: NO (zzpv↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ zzq.zzbmk
├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzpv
│    Leaking: NO (zzpy↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ zzpv.zzboy
├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzpy
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ zzpy.zzzr
├─ com.mypackage.ui.main.MainActivity
│    Leaking: NO (NavHostController↓ is not leaking and Activity#mDestroyed is false)
│    ↓ MainActivity.navController
├─ androidx.navigation.NavHostController
│    Leaking: NO (NavHostFragment↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ NavHostController.mLifecycleOwner
├─ androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
│    Leaking: NO (FragmentManagerImpl↓ is not leaking and Fragment#mFragmentManager is not null)
│    ↓ NavHostFragment.mChildFragmentManager
├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl
│    Leaking: NO (HashMap↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ FragmentManagerImpl.mActive
├─ java.util.HashMap
│    Leaking: NO (HashMap$HashMapEntry[]↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ HashMap.table
├─ java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry[]
│    Leaking: NO (HashMap$HashMapEntry↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ array HashMap$HashMapEntry[].[0]
├─ java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry
│    Leaking: NO (FragmentStateManager↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ HashMap$HashMapEntry.value
├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager
│    Leaking: NO (FeedFragment↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ FragmentStateManager.mFragment
├─ com.mypackage.ui.main.feed.FeedFragment
│    Leaking: NO (Fragment#mFragmentManager is not null)
│    ↓ FeedFragment.feedBinding
│                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ com.mypackage.databinding.FragmentMainFeedBindingImpl
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ FragmentMainFeedBindingImpl.clFeedFragmentRoot
│                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
╰→ androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this)
     mContext instance of com.mypackage.ui.main.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
     View#mParent is null
     View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
     View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
     key = 991c9d5b-7065-4c88-9b79-74ad67f5f72d
     watchDurationMillis = 77959
     retainedDurationMillis = 72956
     retainedHeapByteSize=18132), ApplicationLeak(className=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout, leakTrace=
```

I need help in resolving the leak.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In FeedFragment.onDestroyView() you'll need to set FeedFragment.feedBinding to null (the binding holds a reference to the view, so you need to let go of the binding object after onDestroyView()

Comment: Accurate!! You are late to the party though:) Figured it out a while back. Thank you very much though, you reaffirmed.